# Circuit Breaker Simulation in Matlab with Mayr and Cassie Equations

Tags: high-voltage, matlab, simulink, arc, circuit-breaker

I'm trying to understand how to model arc circuit breaker.

There is a simulation example as called Mayr and Cassie Circuit in Matlab&Simulink.

I have examined Mayr and Cassie Differential Equations to understand parameter determination in this circuit.

I simulated to see how to effect by changing input and output parameter R,L and C values. I see that only amplitude of current and voltage changed.

What parameters should I arrange to change arc time and arc voltage?

Example can be found in the following link:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/cassie-and-mayr-arc-models-for-a-circuit-breaker.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a link or image of the specific circuit you are simulating.

Comment: Better. I don't know anything about arcs but as long as no one else is answering, I could ask if you are aware that a passive linear networks with RLC on their own won't change the fundamental tone of a sinusoidal input source? The RLC networks can be tuned for a resonance frequency and Q factor, but you still need to supply that frequency at the source... The arc will probably add harmonics as it is non-linear so when it arcs it might not look sinusoidal anymore. Also, I would also expect that 'arc voltage' is something that is adjusted in the arc model and not anywhere else.